# Can a mat-checkbox be used as a mat-label?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a mat-form-field that has a checkbox which, when checked, will enable the the form field. I am sure I can do this through working on the css but did not know if there might be something I am missing that might allow it to be done much more simply.

```
        <mat-form-field id="critical-qty-mat-form-field" fxFlex="50">
          <mat-label>
            <mat-checkbox id="critical-qty-needed-mat-form-field" labelPosition="before">Critical Qty
            </mat-checkbox>
          </mat-label>
          <input type="number" matInput formControlName="criticalQuantityInput">
         </mat-form-field>
```

I know I can not be the first person to want to do this but my googling has failed me.

Comment: Try it!........

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just needed to override the css with the following

pointer-events: auto;

This let me keep the css styling for the label but made my check box clickable.